# Can I Convert a String to an Enum Value in D?

Tags: enums, type-conversion, d

I have the following enum declared which using a string as its underlying value:

```
enum IssueType : string {
    STUDENT_LEAVING = "leaving",
    STUDENT_CONFLICT = "conflict",
    NEEDS_ARCHIVE = "archive",
    OTHER = "other"
}
```

I want to be able to do the following:

```
string s = "conflict";
IssueType type = std.conv.to!IssueType(s);
```

Currently, it is only possible to convert from a string to the enum by providing a case-sensitive match for one of the enum value names, like in this case the string `"STUDENT_CONFLICT"` would be accepted, while I want `"conflict"` to be accepted.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simply cast the string to the `enum` type.

```
IssueType type = cast(IssueType)s;
```